# Insatpyselenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instapy

InstaPy Version: 0.6.15
.*.  .*.  .*.  .*.  .*.  .*.  ._.

```
Workspace in use: "/root/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crazy/Desktop/instapy-quickstart/quickstart.py", line 22, in <module>
    session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 123, in set_selenium_local_session
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 179, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Comment: @cruisepandey As per the dup target, not having the _display_ can't be the sole reason for _Process unexpectedly closed with status 1_ and to execute with `--headless` can't be the single stop solution in such cases. More information is needed in this case.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Well, there was not enough information provided by OP, such as code trials, HTML, etc. Also, you have a Selenium Gold badge as well, if you think this is not a duplicate or if you think this can be answered in a better way, feel free to reopen the ticket. You are welcome to do that. I won't mind. Good luck!

Comment: @cruisepandey I understand there wasn't enough information, so the _Close_ reason shouldn't be a dup target but _Needs details or clarity_, agree?

Comment: @DebanjanB: Agreed!

Comment: @cruisepandey If you at all _**agree**_ I think the best way to pay forward would be to remove the dup target and _Reopen_ the question.

Comment: @DebanjanB: I can do that, but I am curious why you've not re-opened it yet?

Comment: @cruisepandey Simply by invalidating your dup hammer I won't be able to suggest you if there's something right or wrong in the validation. The correct way should be to interact and reach to a common conciseness. That's how we as a community can prosper. Hence my comments.

Comment: @DebanjanB: There you go! Happy learning!